# Python: Text File Reading Special Characters Issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

appreciate any help I can get. I have searched page after page and have not found a solution that works for my code. Sorry to ask a some what of a redundant question.

I am using Python 3.6.0 and for the life of me cannot get the darn thing to read my special characters. I have a text file with "ā" and am trying to have my module read how many of ā are in the line and the location of them. I have the text file saved as utf-8 encoding and have added utf-8 encoding just about everywhere I can think and it still will not read that the character exists. I am not getting a trace back error or any error at all, that's probably why I'm stumped.

```
import sys
import re
# coding=utf-8 
with open("text1.txt","r", encoding='utf-8') as rf, open('text2.txt','w', encoding='utf-8') as wf:
        y = 'ā'
        for line in rf:
                VarTest = line.count(y)
                        if VarTest == 1:
                        VarLocation = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(line) if char == y]
```

The counter will not count that the character was on the line and I'm pretty sure my code for "VarLocation" is incorrect, but VarTest won't even read/count the darn thing.

Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Try doing a `print(VarTest)` before `if VarTest == 1`. Also, change the condition to `if VarTest >= 1`. I tried this code out and it works fine with the condition modified.

Answer (score 0):

HaHa yes, thank you. I also realized I had 2.7.13 python open and as soon as I closed it. The module started working both ways. Thank you again!!